# Filter RDD to get a clean list excluded certain values from another list

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to delete lists from an RDD file which contains certain elements. But the results stay the same. For example,

```
exclude = ["lol",".ico","Special:"]    
data.take(10) =['lolaaaaaa',''abcdes','Special:aaaaa','qqqqq']
```

I expect to get the result after flatMap like:

```
['abcdes','qqqqq']
```

But I still got results: ['lolaaaaaa',''abcdes','Special:aaaaa','qqqqq']

Here is my code:

```
def findUnique(line):
   exclude = ["lol",".ico","Special:"]
   return [el for el in line if not any(ignore in el for ignore in exclude)]

listAfterDelete = data.filter(findUnique)
print listAfterDelete.take(10)
```

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

The function that you filter on should return a Boolean (True/False) value therefore something like this should work (not tested) as a definition for findUnique:

```
def findUnique(line):
  exclude = ["lol",".ico","Special:"]
  return not any(ignore in el for ignore in exclude)
```